# Existing Core Data Database Not Uploading to iCloud When Enabling iCloud On My App

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, icloud

I have a simple application out in the App Store which is a `UITableView` which is populated by the user filling in some `UITextField`s in a view that's called up modally. The user presses save and everything goes saved to Core Data and using `NSFetchedResultsControllers`, the `UITableView` is updated.

I am now updating my application to introduce `iCloud` synching (and an iPad version).

I'm new to `iCloud` development and although the post I followed http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452 is a few years old, it mostly works for me.

**Problem**

Without going further into other issues, the one issue I'm having right now is the fact that if I'm running the App Store version of my app with some data (which doesn't have iCloud enabled), when I update my app using my development build in Xcode, I'm expecting my original data to still be there and to therefore upload to iCloud.

I don't have a check box in my app saying don't upload, but I will get to that. For now, the problem is I'm starting with a completely blank database when I update my app, though I suspect it's just a problem with my code actually showing the data now because in the settings of my device, it's showing 9.7 KB of data stored in iCloud (I made sure to remove the iCloud backup data before doing this test).

I've adjusted my App Id in the Developer Portal to include iCloud and adjusted Xcode to include that, while creating a new SSL certificate in the Developer and important the new provisioning profiles into Xcode.

**Update: Made a lot of changes to my app and removing old code**

Here's my `App Delegate` `persistentStoreCoordinator` code: (following the advice from Tom's answer)

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Planner.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                              };
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    NSPersistentStore *ps = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *url = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSDictionary *iCloudOptions = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"EnvysStore"
                              };
    NSPersistentStore *store = [[_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] firstObject];

    store = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:ps toURL:url options:iCloudOptions withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

However, upon running my app, the app crashes with :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'nil is not a valid persistent store' on the 

    store = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:ps toURL:url options:iCloudOptions withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
```

**Problem**

So the problem is, when I have the app Store version of my app with some data and then update to this version, firstly the app crashes as above, but once I get that fixed, I want my existing data to be migrated to the cloud.

Any guidance on this would be massively appreciated!

Comment: iCloud core data has changed a _lot_ in ios7. Any guide that is older than that is obsolete and should not be followed. Furthermore, apple themselves recommend that you don't attempt to mix iCloud enabled apps running iOS 7 and older versions. Find an ios7 guide and follow that. Objc.io had a good one a while ago.

Comment: Dear @jrturton - thanks so much for the reply. The good news is I'm using only iOS 7 in my applications and not working between other versions and I've found an article from the site you were talking about a few minutes ago: http://www.obj.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html. 

Unfortunately for novices, although it includes code, it doesn't exactly say where that need sot be inserted.. should I perhaps create a new question referencing that article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Without going further into other issues, the one issue I'm having right now is the fact that if I'm running the App Store version of my app with some data (which doesn't have iCloud enabled), when I update my app using my development build in Xcode, I'm expecting my original data to still be there and to therefore upload to iCloud.

It's not that simple. Core Data's iCloud integration uses transaction logs to sync changes. Transaction logs are generated every time you save changes to the persistent store file. If you just add iCloud support while existing data is present, no transactions are generated for that data. No transaction logs, no sync, and your data remains local.

To move existing data to iCloud you need to migrate the persistent store to a new file, in the process generating transactions for all of that existing data. The easiest way to do this is by calling `[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:]`, which takes the same options as you use when adding a persistent store file. Migrate your local store to a new iCloud-enabled store and, if everything is working, you'll get transaction logs and the data will upload.

If your persistent stores are very large, you may need to use custom migration code. Most of the time though, the built-in migration method is just fine.

Comment: Dear Tom - Thanks very much for that and that makes sense. Is this the case in iOS 7 only apps as well, that existing local data needs to basically be migrated over to the cloud first? If so, this makes sense and the only thing I'm not sure about is what argument to use for the migratePersistentStore - it's wanting to take a NSPersistentStore as an argument - should I create an instance of that and set it to nil before calling this?

Comment: I figure I need to create something like :     NSPersistentStore *store = [[_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] firstObject]; in the persistentStore but when I run the code migratePersistent, it crashes with "nil is not a valid persistent store".

Comment: That's what you need to do, but before that you need to add the persistent store using the old non-iCloud options so that there's an `NSPersistentStore` to migrate. So (a) add the store without iCloud, then (b) migrate to iCloud.

Comment: Thanks Tom and I'm so sorry for so many questions. Yours will of course be the accepted answer. Having thought about what you said, I went ahead and updated the question to reflect my code and what I think is the way to do it. However I'm getting the crash. This is all very new to me, so the migrating aspect seems like I'm close.. but just not quite there yet!

Comment: The problem in the code is that you're adding the same persistent store twice. The second time is an error, so it fails, but you're not checking the error status so you don't notice that. You should drop the second, redundant call to `addPersistentStore:etc:`.

Comment: Thanks Tom - with that change, the app is running without crashes, but the existing data is unfortunately not there. I'm seeing that my persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChange notification doesn't look like it's being run and I suspect that might have something to do with this still not showing in the UI? Though it's certainly in iCloud

Comment: Success! A bit of working and understand each line and i've got this working now. Data from the migrated version shows up perfectly! A huge thanks Tom for your help with this - I really appreciate it!