# Migrating existing Core Data to iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, icloud, nspersistentstore

I have a simple application which is a `UITableView` that gets populated by the user filling in some `UITextFields` in a different view. This information gets saved to `CoreData` and the `UITableView` gets updated using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I'm now introducing iCloud synching into my environment. With reference to a previously asked question: [Existing Core Data Database Not Uploading to iCloud When Enabling iCloud On My App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593344/existing-core-data-database-not-uploading-to-icloud-when-enabling-icloud-on-my-a/23598504?noredirect=1#comment36258787_23598504) , I am still having issues but it was too messy to update that question with my new code. I am referring specifically to the `WWDC 2013 CoreData` Sessions, as well as [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html). Because my app is iOS 7 only. I'm fairly new to iCloud development and am an intermediate programmer.

I am having some great difficulty migrating my existing data to iCloud when I update from the App Store (non-iCloud) version to the development (iCloud) version. New data syncs across perfectly.

I understand that I need to essentially take my existing store without iCloud and migrate it across to iCloud but it's just not working out for me.

Here's some code to illustrate what I'm working on:

**Update**

I have gone through and thought about this and have removed code that was redundant.

```
 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
 {
     if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
         return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
     }

     NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Planner.sqlite"];
     NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSURL *url = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
     NSError *error = nil;
     _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

     if (url)
     {
         NSLog(@"iCloud is enabled");
         NSDictionary *options = @{
                                   NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                   NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                   };

         NSPersistentStore *localStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];

         [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:localStore toURL:[self iCloudURL] options:[self iCloudStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"iCloud is not enabled");
         NSDictionary *options = @{
                                   NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                   NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                                   };

         if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self iCloudURL] options:options error:&error])
         {
             NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
             abort();

         }

     }

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Reload" object:self userInfo:nil];
});

     return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I am no longer calling the migrateLocalStoreToiCloud method but it is here for reference:

```
/*-(void)migrateLocalStoreToiCloud
{
    //assuming you only have one store.
    NSPersistentStore *store = [[_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] firstObject];
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:store
                                                                                toURL:[self iCloudURL]
                                                                              options:[self iCloudStoreOptions]
                                                                             withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                                error:nil];
    [self reloadStore:newStore];
}
```

*/

The `storeURL`, `storeOptions`, `iCloudURL` and `iCloudStoreOptions` code is:

```
- (NSURL *)iCloudURL
{
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *url = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
     if (url) {
     NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", url);
     } else {
     NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
     }
    return url;
}

-(NSURL *)storeURL{
    return [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Planner.sqlite"];
}


-(NSDictionary *)storeOptions{
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
    return options;
}

-(NSDictionary *)iCloudStoreOptions{
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:@"PlannerStore" forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
    return options;
}
```

**Problem**

When I run this code exactly as it is, I am not presented in the console with Using `Local Storage : 1` and `0` at all, though the data is there.

If I change the `persistentStoreCoordinator` where it first adds the persistentStore to use `[self iCloudStoreOptions]` as the options, the `Using Local Storage 1` and `0` displays, but the data does not on the device.

I'm following the guidance here and I have tried multiple variations of my code including not removing any persistentStore in the reloadStore method but I am completely stuck.

I have read so many posts but it seems that I just cannot find someone who is migrating data from a non-iCloud version to an iCloud version and with examples I have found, there's no code.

I have looked into [this](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/) and while it is a great code set, I've downloaded the code and followed those guidelines where it doesn't remove any persistentStore but it still wouldn't work for me. I can't imagine what I'm trying to achieve is very complicated. I simply need to take the existing non-iCloud data and migrate it over to iCloud.

**Update**

With reading Apple's guide : https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW2 I can see that my `migrateLocaltoiCloud` method is currently wrong with the removing of the `persistentStore`, etc, but I can't figure out how to fix it. If I call this from the `persistentStoreCoordinator`, will it somehow interfere with the `DidChangeNotification`?

I'm really stuck on this and I would appreciate any guidance into the right direction

Comment: You're not checking the return values from most of those calls and throwing away any error status (by passing nil as the `error` parameter), which means you're almost certainly missing out on crucial details of what's happening in this process.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the `reloadStore:` method? Why does it exist at all?

Comment: Dear Tom - thanks for your reply. Having spent the day on this, I have adjusted my persistentStoreCoordinator method and updated the question to reflect this. The reloadStore was a method to essentially go back to the localstore from iCloud, so I thought I could reverse that! My newbieness. But now the persistentStore is updated but its the same effect, there's no  Using Local Store 1 or 1 in the console when the app is run (though the data is there on the device) but this clearly doesn't seem right. 

I'm going to try focus on the errors now but I'm really lost with this

Comment: The code still ignores the return values and the error parameters of the relevant `addPersistentStore:` and `migratePersistentStore:` calls. Did you verify that they look OK while debugging? If not, it's time to take a look and see.

Comment: I'm looking through the code and trying to debug - but I'm so sorry, I'm just so lost (and new to finding out what to do with errors).. how would I debug this appropriately? The NSLog "iCloud is enabled" is getting called, but it's, from what I can see, not actually doing the migration, so it just adds the persistentStore with the non-iCloud options

Comment: You'd do this by looking at the return values and the error parameters of the relevant `addPersistentStore:` and `migratePersistentStore:` calls. You'd do *that* by setting a breakpoint in the method that calls them and seeing what the debugger shows you about them. Or else by using `NSLog` to print out the values.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I've created an answer based on some heavy debugging and I have it working, though there are a few other issues. I can't imagine I'm far from having this working.

Comment: Dear @TomHarrington - any further thoughts with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing an answer here to my question because it's clearer than updating the question and after a lot of debugging, I have this working, to some extent.

With debugging the `addPersistentStore` and `migratePersistentStore` lines of code, I came up with:

```
 NSPersistentStore *localStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];

 NSLog(@"The localStore is %@", localStore);

 NSPersistentStore *migratedStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:localStore toURL:[self iCloudURL] options:[self iCloudStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

 NSLog(@"The migrationStore is %@", migratedStore); 

The NSLog value of localStore is: The localStore is <NSSQLCore: 0x13451b100> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/DDB71522-C61D-41FC-97C7-ED915D6C46A4/Documents/Planner.sqlite)

The NSLog value of migratedStore is: (null)
```

With debugging, I could see essentially the same thing, that migrateStore was always null.

I changed the code slightly:

```
 NSPersistentStore *migratedStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:localStore toURL:storeURL options:[self iCloudStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
```

For the URL to be the storeURL and suddenly, everything started working, where storeURL:

```
 NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Planner.sqlite"];
```

My outputs were:

```
The localStore is <NSSQLCore: 0x14ee09b50> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/CC0F7DA0-251F-46D6-8E43-39D63062AED2/Documents/Planner.sqlite)
[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](771): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~5BD59259-7758-42FB-986F-DDD173F75ED3:EnStor
The migrationStore is <NSSQLCore: 0x157e260b0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/A08D183D-ECD4-4E72-BA64-D21727DE7A3E/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~CB6C3699-8BF1-47DB-9786-14BCE1CD570A/EnStor/771D2B0B-870A-428E-A9A8-5DAE1295AF53/store/Planner.sqlite)
```

The Using Local Store went from 1 to 0 and my data from the App Store version of the app continued to be there through the migration to the new version. This was the output the first time I ran the app after the upgrade.

This is great news.

Every subsequent time I ran the app though, the data continued to migrate and so I would end up with duplicate results.

The issue also is the fact that when adding a new device, it doesn't pull down the information to the new device.

I don't quite understand why using storeURL as the url for migratePersistentStore worked?

I also don't want each new device to basically add a new persistent store if one already exists and I don't know how I would get around this and also I don't want the migration to occur again and again. It should only occur the one time.

I'm getting there, but still a lot of work to be done!